# Jenkins does not show styles in HTML though they are allowed in CSP

Tags: jenkins

I publish an HTML report generated by my tests through Jenkins HTML Publisher, but the report does not show any css styles. There is an error in the browser's console:

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-THOk1r6rC4+HM3k9+2D9L3LsMds3+2crJ1U6Db9rsEk='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

I tried to change the policy through `Jenkins.xml` both to `style-src 'usafe-inline'` as well as leave the parameter empty at all. The changes are applied and shown on the System Properties page:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJSEK.png)
but the console still shows the error and styles are not shown in the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a [bug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33383). Editing of the jenkins.xml gives no result, a workaround is editing the CSP through jenkins console.